# Ubuntu 16.04 - GUI freezes on login start page

Tags: ubuntu, login, gui, freeze

I am unable to enter anything at the login screen; it just freezes directly after the page shows. The cursor inside the login form blinks about 10 times, then it stops. I can't move the mouse or use the keyboard.

I already entered the secure mode and triggered update, upgrade and dist-upgrade via the root shell it made no difference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We were able to solve it by starting the shell in secure mode and executing the following commands.

```
  apt-get update 
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
  apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
  apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev    //I think this packet was the problem
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vmware

  reboot
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my exact problem. I was trying to fix problems with my video and followed this https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers and after reboot got the same problem as you (don't know if it was because of what I did or not). I installed `xserver-xorg-input-all` which pulled in `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` and now it works again.

Comment: `apt-get update` then `apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev` then `/etc/init.d/lightdm restart` worked for me.  Of course, I did these as root user.

Comment: @User1, add this as an Answer please, not as comment. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: A variation on this solved my problem. "sudo apt-get update" then "apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all", during that install it was suggested to install xinput, so "sudo apt-get install xinput". After a reboot things were back to normal.

Answer (score 8):

To Simplify @Black's answer, run these as root:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
/etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

No reboot required on this solution.

Comment: Also needed `xserver-xorg-core` as a dependency for `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` but still didn't work.

Comment: @Shayan: did the original poster "Black" 's answer work for you?

Comment: @User1 Did this leave you at a black screen with only a flashing white cursor "_" (underscore) on it?   EDIT: I had to make sure my ethernet was actually *working* so it could really download "`xserver-xorg-input-evdev`"

Comment: @frank no it did not, what actually worked for me at the end was this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1051125/777279 as far as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything, for weeks, all day long. I finally went to Driver Manager and changed my video driver to NVIDIA, and that fixed it.

Ironically, NVIDIA was the recommended setting. No idea why that wasn't chosen. It wasn't me - Linux set that.

Anyway, let me know. YMMV.

Comment: Linux doesn't set jack. Maybe some of the Ubuntu topping which is supposed to do some magic in the back. Anyway, I'm voting down because this is not a real answer. No background on how this solution works, no documentation that explains anything. Just a best guess.